# Overwrite data associated with a specific ObjectId?

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, url-shortener

I am attempting to to change the "OriginalUrl" that is already created and stored in the database under a random ObjectId like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b1551d571231d26444d5c35"),
    "Title" : "Test5",
    "Code" : "n3b4nb_jxnm2",
    "OriginalUrl" : "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api-mac?view=aspnetcore-2.1",
    "Url" : null
}
```

I have a Post Get and Delete method working but my Put method is not doing what I understand to be the way to do this according to [https://learn.microsoft.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41493327/mongodb-and-asp-core-update-only-a-key-value-pair-instead-of-whole-model)

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Update(string id, [FromBody] string su)
        {
            var gameFromDb = await _repo.GetAsync(id);
            if (gameFromDb == null)
            {
                return new NotFoundResult();
            }

            su = gameFromDb;
           // await _repo.Update(su);
            return new OkObjectResult(su);
        }
```

I am still learning so I sincerely apologize if this is an obvious answer that I have not yet discovered on this site or elsewhere.

**Update:**

```
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Update(string id, [FromBody] string su)
        {
            return (await _repo.Update(ObjectId.Parse(id)))
                ? (IActionResult)Ok("Updated Successfully")
                : NotFound();
        }
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public async Task<bool> Update(ObjectId id)
{
    var filter = new ShortUrl("_id", 10);
    var replacement = new BsonDocument { { "_id", 10 }, { "x", 2 } };

    var r = _db.Urls.ReplaceOne(filter, replacement);
    return r.IsAcknowledged

}
```

**Update:**

I realize there are similar articles to this such as:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41493327](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41493327/mongodb-and-asp-core-update-only-a-key-value-pair-instead-of-whole-model)

And:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483648](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483648/update-operation-in-mongodb-and-asp-net-core)

But neither helped. I don't want to hard code "First Name", "John" to "FirstName", "Jack". I need to be able to search the Id associated with "John" and change First Name to what ever the user passes. I was thinking something like this:

```
public async Task<bool> Update(ObjectId id)
        {
var filter = Builders<ShortUrl>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, id);
var r = await _db.UrlsFindOneAndUpdate(filter, update);
return r.IsAcknowledged;
}
```

but obviously this is incorrect. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation on updating](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.6/reference/driver/crud/writing/#update-and-replace)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found absolutely nothing useful in helping me solve this but I eventually got this to work:

**Controller class:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(string id, [FromBody]ShortUrl entity)
        {                 
            if (await _repo.Update(id, entity))
            {
                return Ok();
            }

            return NotFound();
        }
    }
```

**Repository Class:**

```
   public async Task<bool> Update(string Id, ShortUrl shortUrl)
    {
      var objId = ObjectId.Parse(Id);

        var ub = Builders<ShortUrl>.Update;

        var updates = new List<UpdateDefinition<ShortUrl>>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(shortUrl.Title))
        {
            updates.Add(
                ub.Set(x => x.Title, shortUrl.Title));
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(shortUrl.OriginalUrl))
        {
            updates.Add(
                ub.Set(x=>x.OriginalUrl,shortUrl.OriginalUrl));
        }

        if (updates.Count == 0) return false;

       var result = await _db.Urls.UpdateOneAsync(
            x => x.Id == objId,
            ub.Combine(updates));

        return result.ModifiedCount > 0;
```